# Solidity loop and write data in one function

Tags: solidity

Is solidity cannot loop and write data? It must be write one by one?
Here is my smart contract function:

```
function purchaseItem1(address _to, uint256[] _tokenId) public {
        address _from;
        for(uint i = 0; i < _tokenId.length; i++){
                _from = itemOwner[_tokenId[i]];
                itemOwnerCount[_to] = itemOwnerCount[_to]+1;
                itemOwnerCount[_from] = itemOwnerCount[_from]-1;
                itemOwner[_tokenId[i]] = _to;
                items[_tokenId[i]].available = false;
                availableCount = availableCount-1;
        }
    }
```

In my front end I have a group of checkbox with same name.
After I checked few of it and I will pass the value in array as uint[] tokenId.